# How with HTML do you make a site with two columns, where one column stays a constant pixel size where the other changes with the size of the window?

Tags: html, css

For example, like Reddit where the right log in system div stays a constant size as you make the window smaller and the left statements just become taller and less wide.

I was thinking something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#1{
    width:(this is where I get confused)
    float:left;
    height: 800px;
}

#2{
    width: 200px;
    float:right
    height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Why not put it into fiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYd9w/9/ is this your desired output??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYd9w/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the left one to expand while the right one stays at a constant size:

```
#1 {
    height:800px;
    margin-right:210px;
}

#2 {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    height:800px;
}
```

Comment: m surprised.....OP has less rep so dont know abt him.....bt `div` name starting with a number!!!??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYd9w/14/ can you please check this if it the desired output of yours??

Comment: sorry it was just for the sake of the example I didn't realize you aren't allowed to do that :/

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating both float and width on the variable column

Answer (score 0):

```
#1 {
    height:800px;
    position:absolute; 
}

#2 {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    height:800px;
    position:absolute;

}
```